# Autolayout issue AlignParentBottom

Tags: ios, autolayout

[image]This is my first time to use autolayout in iOS and I'm facing a small issue.
The thing I'm trying to implement is to have a UIView as a content view and in the footer there should be a UIImageView, the UIView should have a dynamic height where it covers the full view controller till it reaches the UIImageView at the bottom. I have gone through multiple scenarios but none of them worked.

Something similar to LinearLayout with vertical alignment in Android and AlignParentBottom=true for the UIImageView.

Your help is appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: please check my answer below. if you have any problem please comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a UIView stacked over a UIImageView as shown in the image below.

[image: View Layout]

1. Lay the views more or less how you want them
2. Add leading, trailing, top, and bottom constraints  to the image view (footer) so that it stays stuck to the bottom and resizes it's width. Add also an aspect ratio constraint.
   [image]
3. Add leading, trailing, top, and bottom constraints to the UIView.

[image]

You should be good to go.

**EDIT**

After looking at how you set up your constraints, it seems they are wrong. I've added the constraints above for reference. Just tested it and worked like a charm on iPad.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I have updated my constraints accordingly but it's not working, I have updated my post with  an image

Comment: @AhmadJ.Hamad I checked your constraints setup... it seems that they are not setup correctly. I updated the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem. You need to set fix size of Imageview at Bottom and Your UIView will be Adjusted as per the Screen size . right .

Please Set constrain Like this .

---

**Step 1:-** Let's Change Main View (UIViewController's View)'s Color to Yellow    Color.So, we can identify difference easily.

[image]

**Step 2 :-** Take Imageview in UIViewController's View and stick it to bottom with Fixed Imageview Height. (Let's Take Imageview Height = 55)

So, Set it's Constrain Like this ,

--> Leading Space to 0 from Superview.

--> Trialing Space to 0 from Superview.

--> Bottom space to 0 from bottom Layoutguide.

--> Now give fixed Height 55 to Imageview. (You can change it According to your Requirement)

--> Update Frame to Stick UIImageview as per Constrain.

[image]

**Step 3:-** Now take New UIView and set BackgroundColor RedColor. (Adjustable UIView as per ScreenSize, I have temporary set GreenColor to Imageview)

[image]

**Step 4:-** Now this is the main Step. Set your Constrain to 0 from All the side.

(Leading = 0 from superview ,
Trialling = 0 from superview ,
Topspace =0 from superview or Toplayout guide , And
Bottom space=0 from **Imageview**)

[image]

**Step 5:-** and the Last step is to Check **Preview** in All Devices.

[image]

I hope this info is enough for you to understand your question.